# How to format date after getting the date of a past email?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail

I'm wiring a script that pulls CSV files from my email and moves them to a drive folder for easier importing, and I want to rename the files to the date of the email as MMddyyyy, however, when I format the date after using getDate(), the file is renamed to date that the script is being ran and not the date the email was received.

```
//const fileType = ['csv'];
//const processedLabel = "Processed TBD Data";
//var res = GmailApp.search(query);
const dir = DriveApp.getFolderById("<folderID>");
const query = 'has:attachment from:it label:EOD-TBD';
var rmLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('EOD-TBD');
var newLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Processed TBD Data');

function countThreads() { 

  //Find threads within "EOD-TBD" that have an attachment
  var TBD_Threads = GmailApp.search(query);

  for (var m = 0; m < TBD_Threads.length; m++) { //Counts threads
  var threads = TBD_Threads[m].getMessages()
  
  for (var j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
    var date = threads[j].getDate()
    var nDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")
    Logger.log("Processing Message from: " + nDate)
    var att=threads[j].getAttachments()
    for (var k = 0; k < att.length; k++){
      var attachmentBlob = att[k].copyBlob().setName(nDate);
      //var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
      var file = dir.createFile(attachmentBlob);

    }
  }
  TBD_Threads[m].removeLabel(rmLabel);
  TBD_Threads[m].addLabel(newLabel);
}
}
```

I can't, for the life of me, find out how to format the date properly. If I log 'date', it'll show the correct date of the email that's being processed, but it's showing it as [day][numbered day][month][year][time].

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

```js
var nDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

to

```js
var nDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT-0600", "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

If I understand correctly, the timezone that getDate() was using was different than the timezone declaration in formatDate(), so it was subbing todays date?
Either way, once I changed the timezones to match, it formatted correctly with the date of the email.